# Specify number of items in tuple

Tags: types, parameters, tuples, julia

I want to define the parameters of an array of tuples.
I don't know how many tuples there will be in the array, but I know exactly what type and how many items there will be in each tuple.

I don't want to use [Vararg](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/types/#vararg-tuple-types), since there is no casual number of trailing elements. Each tuple contains exactly `n` `Float64` numbers. `n` depends on user input.

How can I tell to the program that each tuple contains `n` numbers?

Comment: I think you are looking for `Array{NTuple{N,Float64},1}` or you could use a  number other than 1 if you have a more than 1d array of these tuples

Comment: Thanks @spencerlyon2 ! Can you give me a link to the documentation please? cause I couldn't find it

Comment: But now I have another problem: what if I put that  Array as a parameter of a function? How do I specify that they are tuples of length n? I tried adding `n` as another parameter: `f(n::Int8,array:Array{NTuple{Int64(n),Float64},1})` but it doesn't work. I get: ` LoadError: UndefVarError: n not defined`

Comment: You'll need to make n a type parameter of the function instead of an argument

Comment: How can I do that? :/

Comment: Writing this code will be tricky until you are comfortable with type parameters and how inference works. For now, I'd suggest using [FixedSizeArrays.jl](https://github.com/SimonDanisch/FixedSizeArrays.jl) as it efficiently implements what you want.

Comment: That's interesting! I'll probably use that. But just for curiosity:  could you show  me the tricky solution? Maybe I won't understand it, but at least I will see all the possible paths to solve the problem

Comment: `function myfunction{N}(array::Array{NTuple{N,Float64},1})` (inspired from [the docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/#an-advanced-example))

Comment: Is there a particular reason why N must be Int64? Why can't it be Int8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spencer is correct; the type of a length-n tuple is written as `NTuple{n,T}`. Here's an example of how to create an array with this type:

```
julia> n = 4
4

julia> A = Array{NTuple{n,Float64},1}(0)
0-element Array{NTuple{4,Float64},1}

julia> push!(A, (1,2,3,4))
1-element Array{NTuple{4,Float64},1}:
 (1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)

julia> NTuple{n,Float64}[(0,0,0,0),(1,1,1,1)]
2-element Array{NTuple{4,Float64},1}:
 (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
 (1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0)
```

In the first case I used `push!` to grow the array incrementally, and in the second case I explicitly passed elements to initialize the array with.